# Aggregating data based on string value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have thousands of documents in my index and what I'm trying to do is aggregate documents with the same date and display how many there are with that date. The dates are in strings. To give you a better picture of what I want, say the field for the date is called arrivalDate and each document has a specific arrivalDate. I want the data to be displayed something like this:

> 20110105  :  5 records
>
> 20120501  :  2 records
>
> 20120602  :  15 records

and so forth. This is basically like a `GROUP BY` SQL query except using elastic search. How do I build such a query using elastic search?

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't save date field as strings. Elasticsearch has several datatypes and 'date' type is one of them. 
<br/>Benefit of this - 
* You get to use many common functionality of 'date' type field which are inbuilt, like making date histogram. You can also compare dates and have filters like newer or older to some date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `term` aggregation. It will look something like this.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_bu_date": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "arrivalDate"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I received an error when executing that command. My error reads: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [arrivalDate] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.